# Create a zip of folders using zipfile

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have a folder called `my_folder` at the following Path `/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/my_folder`. The folder `my_folder` contains more folders like `323456`, `987654` etc. Those folders contain some content. I want to create a zip of all those folders called `myzip.zip` such that when someone unzips it they see all those folders like `323456`, `987654` at the root.

**My Code**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile


DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path("/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/my_folder")
ZIPPED_FILE_DIR = Path("/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/my_zip")


def get_list_of_all_folders(download_dir: Path):
    return [f for f in download_dir.iterdir() if download_dir.is_dir()]


def zip_files():
    folder_list = get_list_of_all_folders(DOWNLOAD_DIR)
    with ZipFile(ZIPPED_FILE_DIR / "my_zip.zip", "w") as zip:
        # writing each file one by one
        for folder in folder_list:
            zip.write(folder)


zip_files()
```

I have a function called `get_list_of_all_folders` where it goes to `my_folder` and gets a list of all the folders inside it that we want to zip. Then I use that `folder_list` to zip up each folder as part of my final zip called `my_zip.zip`. However there is something really wrong with my code and I am not sure what? The `my_zip.zip` is only 35 kb small when I know for a fact I am zipping up content over 2 gigabytes.

I looked at the zipfile [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) but did not find much help here as there are not many examples.

Answer (score 1):

`ZipFile.write` expects to be supplied with the name of a file to write to the zip, not a folder.

You will need to iterate over the files in each folder and call `write` for each one. For example:

```
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile


DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path("/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/my_folder")
ZIPPED_FILE_DIR = Path("/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/my_zip")


def scan_dir(zip, dir, base_dir):
    for f in dir.iterdir():
        if f.is_dir():
            scan_dir(zip, f, base_dir)
        else:
            # First param is the path to the file, second param is
            # the path to use in the zip and when extracted. I just
            # trim base_dir off the front.
            zip.write(f, str(f)[len(str(base_dir)):])


def zip_files():
    with ZipFile(ZIPPED_FILE_DIR / "my_zip.zip", "w") as zip:
        for f in DOWNLOAD_DIR.iterdir():
            scan_dir(zip, f, DOWNLOAD_DIR)


zip_files()
```

There's probably a neater way to trim off the base directory, but this was done quickly :)

Comment: How would i do that while still making sure that when i unzip my zipfile i end up unzipping my folders like `323456`, `987654` etc rather than individual files? Can you show by adding code please?

Comment: You need to provide the filename including the path and it will retain that path within the zip file and when extracted. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write for documentation of the `write` method. Without testing, I believe that you can give the filename as you wish in the first parameter (as long as it is a valid way to find the file on disk) and then provide the second parameter with the path you want it to use when extracted.

Comment: got it , i can try that. if possible would love it if you can provide a working example as i do find the doc a bit hard to understand accurately.

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [shutil.make_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive)

Below example taken from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#archiving-example

```
>>> import os
>>> from shutil import make_archive
>>> archive_name = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', 'myarchive'))
>>> root_dir = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.ssh'))
>>> make_archive(archive_name, 'zip', root_dir)
'/Users/tarek/myarchive.zip'
```

**EDIT:**

Code using ZipFile library

```
import zipfile
import os

class ZipUtilities:
    def toZip(self, file, filename):
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w')
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            zip_file.write(file)
        else:
            self.addFolderToZip(zip_file, file)
        zip_file.close()

    def addFolderToZip(self, zip_file, folder):
        for file in os.listdir(folder):
            full_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
            if os.path.isfile(full_path):
                print('File added: ' + str(full_path))
                zip_file.write(full_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
                print('Entering folder: ' + str(full_path))
                self.addFolderToZip(zip_file, full_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    utilities = ZipUtilities()
    filename = 'newfile.zip'
    directory = 'foldername'
    utilities.toZip(directory, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, i actaully want to know how to do this using zipfile as i know i can do so using shutil.make_archive